# find and gzip a directory recursively without a directory/file test

Tags: bash, backup, gzip

I'm working on improving our bash backup script, and would like to move away from rsync and towards using gzip and a "find since last run timestamp" system. I would like to have a mirror of the original tree, except have each destination file gzipped. However, if I pass a destination path to gzip that does not exist, it complains. I created the test below, but I can't believe that this is the most efficient solution. Am I going about this wrong?

Also, I'm not crazy about using `while read` either, but I can't get the right variable expansion with the alternatives I've tried, such as a `for file in 'find' do`.

Centos 6.x. Relevant snip below, simplified for focus:

```
cd /mnt/${sourceboxname}/${drive}/ && eval find . -newer timestamp | while read objresults; 
  do
    if [[ -d "${objresults}" ]]
    then
    mkdir -p /backup/${sourceboxname}/${drive}${objresults}
    else
    cat /mnt/${sourceboxname}/${drive}/"${objresults}" | gzip -fc > /backup/${sourceboxname}/${drive}"${objresults}".gz
    fi
  done
touch timestamp  #if no stderr
```

Comment: Why the `eval`? `find .` could be simply `find`. What is wrong with `while read`? Both `while` and `read` are shell built-ins, they’re fast. What you got wrong is `cat` usage – it is not a built-in and can be replaced by stdin redirection. Why quoting only parts of the paths? I suspect a slash is missing in `${drive}${objresults}`. I suggest using `pwd` built-in instead of repeating `/mnt/${sourceboxname}/${drive}/`.

Comment: And where does `${objtrim}` come from? Maybe providing the complete source would be a good idea.

Comment: @Palec : My fault-- it's all the same variable: `${objresults}`. I edited above to correct. You're right about eval. Maybe I'm thick, but how would I use pure stdin instead of `cat`; I thought `while read` terminates the pipe and stores stdin as the variable?

Comment: I had stdin of gzip command in my mind. See my answer. `cat` is extremely overused in such scenarios, it is necessary only when con`cat`enating more files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proposed changes from my comments incorporated, I suggest this code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
src="/mnt/$sourceboxname/$drive"
dst="/backup/$sourceboxname/$drive"
timestamp="$src/timestamp"
errors=$({ cd "$src" && find -newer "$timestamp" | while read objresults;
    do
        mkdir -p $(basename "$dst/$objresults")
        [[ -d "$objresults" ]] || gzip -fc < "$objresults" > "$dst/$objresults.gz"
    done; } 2>&1)
if [[ -z "$errors" ]]
then
    touch "$timestamp"
else
    echo "$errors" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: That's perfect. I didn't know you could phrase a test that way-- very elegant.+1